# Random HTTP 500 error in GAE responses (nothing in logs!)

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-500

I failed to find anything related in StackOverflow or anyhow indexed by Google itself. So the last resort before switching part of the infrastructure to another vendor.

We've been running pretty much the same GAE NodeJS (v14) application for a few years, it has several APIs, some of them trivial, and all of them are in CORs mode, so the respective OPTIONS request is processed with this (just for demonstration purpose how simple this one is):

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Cache-Control, Firebase-Token');
res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
res.sendStatus(204);
```

The endpoints are as trivial as spitting out either a static or on-the-fly-generated JSON.

Recently, we've got a number of our frontend app users' reports about failures (easily mapped to one particular GAE service). Upon investigating logs we found nothing. What we could reproduce in our application is once per 10-20 requests one of them (**including the OPTIONS pre-fetch for CORs**) fails with the HTTP 500 and the following response headers:

```
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
content-length: 323
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 08 May 2023 05:37:37 GMT
server: Google Frontend
```

Hitting the same endpoint directly **never** produced this error.

So we introduced cache control headers on responses like this:

```
cache-control: no-store
```

And a few other tricks were tried. Re-deploying and changing instance type had no effect.
This particular GAE instance has no load per se, so this can't be blamed.
What's worse is that an identical setup in the staging environment, though in a separate project, works like a charm.
Again, nothing in the GCP logs at all... Obviously, the request doesn't reach GAE and the error is generated by that load balancer in the middle that we have zero access or visibility into.

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you try re-deploying your application by using [–verbosity flag set to debug](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) and check the output. It might be helpful to find the cause of the error.

Comment: Nothing useful in debug logs, the error surfaces randomly. The decision is made to exit GAE GCP, unfortunately. Can't use the service w/o support.